# How can I allow everyone to see a specific appointment's details in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, exchange-2003

I'm on Outlook 2010/Exchange 2003.

How can I allow everyone on the domain to see the details of a specific appointment on my calendar, without having to send it to everyone? I'd like specific appointments to show the full details, and others to show only free/busy.

I've found options for allowing/disallowing access to the whole calendar, but that's not what I want.

Comment: The best way would be to share the appointment with them.

Comment: I updated my question. I was looking to merely make the details visible, not send it to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

## Mark calander as public

1. Go to the calendar view.
2. Right-click on the appointment, and de-select "Private." Afterwards, "Private" should no longer have a box around the lock icon.

### Before

[image]

### After

[image: Private de-selected]

## Finding the calendar

Others can find your calendar later by clicking *Open Calendar -> From Address Book* on the *Home* ribbon and then typing in your name or email address. Whatever is not marked as private should be visible to them.
[image: Finding a shared calendar]

Comment: None of my appointments are private.